# Evenly space unconnected nodes to form columns

Tags: tikz-styles

How can the first node on tikz be placed to space out evenly? You can see that instead of placing them properly by evenly spacing them out, Overleaf just cuts of the box on the right side. I am looking to make thee columns and under each of the blue box there will be a seperate flowchart.

```
\tikzstyle{heading} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!45]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node[draw] at (0,0) (expected) [heading, xshift=-3cm] {a};
\node (chrome) [heading, right of=expected, xshift=5cm] {b};
\node (firefox) [heading, right of=chrome, xshift=5cm] {c};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The xshift on the first box or draw doesn't seem to be working, for any value.
You help and time is appreciated!

[image: Three unconnected boxes]

Comment: Are you sure, the issue here is not the page margin? tikz pictures will still respect the left margin an will then overflow to the right hand side, if the image is too large.

Comment: Tikz uses a relative bounding box, which means that in your case the leftern most node will not shift to the left in absolute terms. Note that your nodes are 3 times three cm wide plus two times 5cm of xshift. Therefore, your margins may only be 1cm each on an A4 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you to manage your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
heading/.style = {draw,  fill=blue!45, 
                  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}
                        ]
\node (expected)    [heading,right] at (0,0)            {a};
\node (chrome)      [heading]       at (\textwidth/2,0) {b};
\node (firefox)     [heading, left] at (\textwidth,0)   {c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

In above MWE you can change page layout (by use of the `geometry` package) or size of nodes. If you like to have nodes which overflow text borders, than you can use `changepage` package by which you can locally extent text width (for this image).